# Como listar em PHP informações da exchange EXC via API?

Tags: php, json, bitcoin

Usando o PHP, como listar informações da API da EXC, estou com algumas dificuldades e quem puder ajudar,

***Detalhes:*** [LINK API](https://trade.exccripto.com/api/v3/public/getticker?market=DCR_BTC):

Segue exemplo de como tentei fazer:

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents("https://trade.exccripto.com/api/v3/public/getticker?market=DCR_BTC");
    $coins = json_decode($json);
?>

<table style="width:100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>                                                          
   <th>Market</th>
   <th>Bid</th>
   <th>Ask</th>
   <th>Last</th>                                                            
  </tr>                                                       
 <?php foreach ($coins as $coin) { ?>
 <tr>                                                           
  <td><?php echo $coin->Market; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $coin->Bid; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $coin->Ask; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $coin->Last; ?></td>    
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nessa parte do código você esqueceu de especificar o `result` onde acredito ser o a coleção de informações:

`JSON`:

```
{"success":true,
 "message":"",
 "result":[{
     "Market":"DCR_BTC",
     "Bid":0.00452230,
     "Ask":0.00489226,
     "Last":0.00479230
    }]
}
```

***Exemplo com a alteração:***

```
<?php foreach ($coins->result as $coin) { ?>
<tr> 
    <td><?php echo $coin->Market; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $coin->Bid; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $coin->Ask; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $coin->Last; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Ou seja, você não estava colocando a chave proposta no [json](/questions/tagged/json) e por isso não encontrava os itens da sua `table`.